# qttable widget, cell text only as hex

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt4, pyqt4

I have a table widget. I can't figure out how to change input format in each of the cells. At the moment I want it to only accept hex values. How do I do that? I'm using Qt Designer 4.8.6 and PyQt4

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

that can be done using a **custom Delegate** and **QRegexValidator** :

you have to create a custom Delegate where you override the method :

```
QWidget createEditor (self, QWidget parent, QStyleOptionViewItem option, QModelIndex index)
```

so it will return a QLineEdit that have a QRegexValidator, containing the correct pattern.

To set the regex validor on the QLineEdit use :

```
setValidator (self, QValidator)
```

finally, set the custom Delegate on your Table using :

```
setItemDelegate (self, QAbstractItemDelegate delegate)
```